# Need to call a calculated variable & a dataframe object into a sql command....syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a date input in a parameter dictionary. Then, I have created a calculated date field out of the date input in the dictionary. Now, I want to use both the date fields to create a SQL command which I want to pass to a pandas dataframe for further computation. Below is the pandas code -

```
# set parameter values
Dict = {'Date':'2014-10-25'}

# set calculated fields
yr = pd.to_datetime(Dict['Date']).year - 1
mon = pd.to_datetime(Dict['Date']).month
day = 01

CalDateTemp =str(yr)+'-'+str(mon)+'-'+str(day)
CalDate = pd.to_datetime(CalDateTemp)

#create SQL command. This is where I am getting the error while trying to call the calculated field "CalDate". The error says - "descriptor '__add__' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'"
cmd1 = "SELECT A, B, C FROM Table1 WHERE X >= '" + CalDate + "' AND X <= '" + paramDict['Date'] + "'  "

#Define src dictionary
srcDict = {}
srcDict['Table1']      = conio('ServerName', 'TableName', cmd1, chunk, 'native').MssqlToDataFrame()
```

Please have a look. Probably I am going wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked -

```
cmd1 = "SELECT A, B, C FROM Table1 WHERE X >= '" + CalDateTemp + "' AND RPDIVJ_D <= '" + paramDict['Date'] + "'  "
```